# Linq: let statement as a constant?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-6, expression-trees

I am working on a Linq query expression statement, and want to use a **let** statement to set a constant value as part of the query to reduce potential errors.

In my example... (this is total mock up). the let statement "validateCount" is the question.

```
    from referenceRow in context.SomeTable
    // We want 8 in the Take and the results to still be 8 after the where. 
    // instead of typing in the value twice (in this example), i wanted to use a constant value here
    let validateCount = 8

    // sub query expression in my example
    let subQuery = from sub in context.SomeTable
               where sub.SomeColumn == rowReference.SomeColumn
               orderby sub.SomeColumn descending
               select sub

// use the sub query, take X amount, apply filter, check to see if Count() is the same as Take()
where subQuery.Take(validateCount) // this is where we fail. if we put in the constant 8, we are ok.
              .Where(x => x.SomeOtherColumn == "Some value")
              .Count() == validateCount // this is fine
select referenceRow
```

Unfortunately it seems that the let expression "validateCount" which has a single value of 8 in this example, can only work in the comparison part of .Count() but cannot be passed into the .Take() without throwing an exception.

**Limit must be a DbConstantExpression or a DbParameterReferenceExpression.
Parameter name: count**

Looking for a solution to use some user-defined constant in a single code location that can be used in the rest of the query expression, both in the .Take() and .Count() without having to be updated several spots in the code.

*our application allows users to supply their own linq query expression to build their queries. I can't define anything outside the scope of this query, and must be within, using something like a 'let' statement.*

Comment: Are you sure this is `c#`? `let` is from `f#`...

Comment: @CallbackKid let exists in C# too https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause

Comment: apologies, at a glace it looked like you where using `let` as a `var` statement, I now see that its part of a `linq` expression

Comment: To answer your question tho. Why not just use a local variable declared above the expression?

Comment: I can run this without error on LINQ to SQL - what database provider are you using?

Comment: MS SQL / EF6 -  Cant declare outside the scope, as this is all processed real time. That is why im looking for something inline with the Linq statement such as using 'let'.  i cant use "var" or "const" as they are not part of the LINQ query syntax.

Comment: Can you do it in sql? meaning use a top n construct where n is a result from a subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let` statement generates intermediate anonymous type projection (`Select` call) in the query expression tree. EF query provider (as indicated by the exception message) requires `Skip` and `Take` arguments to be resolved to constant or variable values (i.e. to be able to be evaluated locally), hence the `let` cannot be used for that purpose.

Instead, the constants/variables used in `Skip` / `Take` expressions should be defined outside of the query and used inside.

To define a constant value you would use:

```
const int validateCount = 8;
var query = (from .... Take(validateCount) ...);
```

To define a variable value (SQL query parameter):

```
int validateCount = 8;
var query = (from .... Take(validateCount) ...);
```

Here the C# compiler will turn `validateCount` into closure and EF query provider will be happy to bind a parameter (with that value).

> our application allows users to supply their own linq query expression to build their queries. I can't define anything outside the scope of this query, and must be within, using something like a 'let' statement.

When supplying their own queries, the users should follow the same `Skip` / `Take` argument rules as above, i.e. define their constants and variables outside of their queries.

Comment: Did you mean to define `validateCount` and reference `validationCount`?

Comment: Sorry, that was I typo. Of course it should be one and the same constant/variable which replaces the `let` range variable.

Comment: I know I can do what you are saying there, but I also noted in italics that I can't declare anything outside of the statement, as our design doesn't permit that (dynamic code compilation) here, requires only LINQ syntax. Looking to see if there is another way to declare  the 'let'.

Comment: But yes, if I could define them outside the scope, I wouldn't be posting here today. Was looking to see if anyone had another idea / option where I could define inline. I appreciate you attempting to help though.

Comment: Unfortunately no other way. EF specific requirement (only for these 2 methods so far). Still don't understand why the users (not you) cannot declare variables outside their queries since LINQ allows that, but anyway. Good luck.

Comment: Btw, your example is already using external variable inside the query expression tree - the `context` here: `let subQuery = from sub in context.SomeTable`.

Comment: yes, hard to explain... but we expose the context... but the users can build their own queries using linq... but its not in a way where they can code C# / etc.   Its only to build the query expression .. buy design. The users don't see this as "code" but more of an query language. There is no concept of .net other than the Linq expression. If you want to amend your answer and say its not possible within the linq expression, ill accept the answer.

Comment: Not really - I hate to say something is impossible. Apparently `let` operator allows you to define what you want, and works if compiled to code (L2O). The only problem is L2E translation. I've tried to preprocess the query expression with `ExpressionVisitor` as usual, but couldn't find an obvious way to extract a constant value from intermediate `Select`s emit by C# compliler. I guess it could be possible with some complicated algorithm, may be you'll find it :)

Comment: For now, I am going to post this as the answer, though I feel the short answer is No. But at least your post defines the rules about it.  Much appreciated, sorry for the late reply.